# MySQL Multiple Result Sets

Tags: mysql, group-by, create-table

When i run the following query in MySQL it seems to produce multiple result sets.

I expected just one output table with the two average columns being calculated and joined to the table.

why is it producing multiple result sets? Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks,

```
CREATE TABLE test.ratings as SELECT 
    race_id, 
    runner_id, 
    FG, 
    a, 
    b, 
    avg(a) as av, 
    avg(b) as bv, 
    0 as v0, 
    0 as qj 
FROM test.start 
GROUP BY race_id;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` means to create a row for each `race_id`.

Comment: So are you creating the table every time you need to run the calculations? I would think that the "CREATE TABLE" part is one resultset, and the SELECT part is another (See some example output at the bottom of this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html).